# How to automatically update database from html form radio buttons?

Tags: html, django, forms

I am building a django app as part of it I have a page that displays a list of items from my database. I would like each of these to have a pair of radio buttons to allow the user to select an option. The only catch is I would like to do this without a submit button so that the data is changed automatically when the button values are changed. Is this possible? And if it is how would I implement it - does it have to be done through javascript? If so can you please be detailed in your answer (I am not yet comfortable with javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tough one, you definitely need to get comfortable with javascript. However, that is just the beginning. You should use a javascript framework, like jQuery for most of your projects, because it makes everything javascript much easier, and makes browser compatibility a snap.

Then, you'll want to download/install Dajax (www.dajaxproject.com). This allows you to register your python views as Dajax methods, which allows you to call them from javascript on the page.

You would have the buttons in HTML on the page. For the onchange property, you would call a javascript method, passing it the current value (this.value). That javascript method would call a dajax method sending it a return callback method. The callback method is a javascript function that will be called when the Dajax method is done. If you want the callback method to do something and have any parameters, you would return a simplejson.dumps() to the callback method from your Dajax view. In your case, you would probably not need to pass anything back to the callback method, since you are simply saving the change to the database.